# Looking for a read.hclust function

Tags: r

The function write.hclust for hclust objects is available in the  RFLPtools package. However, I can't find a corresponding read.*** function despite Googling. Does anyone know of such a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you should be able to use `read.rflp`.

```
library(RFLPtools)

data(RFLPdata)
res <- RFLPdist(RFLPdata, nrBands = 4)
cl <- hclust(res)
write.hclust(cl, file = "Test.txt", prefix = "Bd4", h = 50)

read.rflp("Test.txt")
```

Returns:

```
   Sample Cluster Cluster.ID Gel
Ni_25_B2  Ni_25       1 Bd4_H50_01  B2
Ni_25_B5  Ni_25       2 Bd4_H50_02  B5
Ni_28_A2  Ni_28       3 Bd4_H50_03  A2`
```